# render form through jquery disables :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In the app/views/alerts/_form.html.erb I have the form (where I've set @alert = Alert.new)

```
<%= form_for( @alert, :remote => true ) do |f| %>
...
```

This works fine and when I click submit I get

*Processing by AlertsController#create as JS*

and I eventually enter app/views/alerts/create.js.erb.

However, if I render the form through a JQuery call the :remote => true seems to be forgotten.

```
$("div.new_alert").html( "<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => "alerts/form" ) ) %>" );
```

Now, when I click submit I get

*Processing by AlertsController#create as HTML*

and the format.html action is run.

How can I render the form through JQuery and still have the processing as JS?

Answer (score 0):

The problem vanished when upgrading from Rails 3.0 to 3.1. I'm not sure what the problem was with 3.0, but most likely I was being sloppy with javascript_include_tag, so JQuery might have been partially broken somehow. I cleaned up the javascript_include_tag when upgrading, and now I don't have the problem anymore.